# How to assign multiple managed identities within Azure Web App for different AD users, linked to different Azure Flexible Postgres roles

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication, azure-postgresql

I have an Azure Web App with AD authentication enabled for a single tenancy. I also have a Azure Flexible Postgres database with AD Authentication enabled.

I have set up two User-Managed-Identities (A & B) and two AD security groups (A & B). I want the permissions to be linked accordingly, so that group A can only use managed identity A, and B only managed identity B. The reason for this is that I have set up two different Postgres Roles within the database, based on each User-Managed-Identity, so that each managed identity has access to a different set of database tables.

My azure app is set to restrict access to users within the two AD Security groups through group assignment to the Enterprise App. However, I cannot work out how I achieve my above requirement, as if I add both User-Managed-Identities to the Web App. Both groups can retrieve a valid access token using the following code:

```
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential({ managedIdentityClientId: '<client-id-of-user-assigned-identity>' })
const accessToken = await credential.getToken("https://ossrdbms-aad.database.windows.net/.default");
```

All they need to know is the Client Id of the User-Managed-Identity which seems a bit of a security risk.

I was hoping that there would be a way of the app attaching the User-Managed-Identity to the User Group, thus restricting the use to the intended audience.

The last headache I have is how to retrieve the client id of the managed identity automatically based on the authentication credentials. I was hoping this could be done within custom JWT claim settings, but it's not obvious how one would go about doing this.

Is what I'm seeking possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use security groups to assign users a role in your application.

I would use the groups the user is in to restrict actions in your application. [configure groups claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims) then in your application to deny the user access to some action.

Then your application only needs one database connection. In the past it was quite common to access the database as the user. And then assign specific database permissions to that user/group.

I would advise against this, just have your application do the access part.

The system/user assigned managed identities are bound to an azure resource (application) and not to a user. This CANNOT be accomplished. It’s not how managed identities work.